# A proof from Grillet's Abstract Algebra: an extension containing roots of finitely many polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

This is *Lemma 4.3* on page 167 of Grillet's book *Abstract Algebra*.

> Every field $K$ has an algebraic extension that contains a root of every nonconstant polynomial with coefficients in $K$.

I don't understand the first step in the proof. Grillet claims that for a finite number of polynomials $f_1,....,f_n$, we can divide them into monic irreducible factors $q_{1i}, ..., q_{ni}$ and repeatedly use the following theorem:

> If $q \in K[x]$ is monic irreducible, then $E = K[x]/(q)$ is a field extension of $K$ such that $\alpha = x + (q)$ is a root of $q$ in $E$.

However, I don't see how we can *repeatedly* use it. Suppose, for instance that $f_1 = a_1 q_{11}\dots q_{1m}$. where $q_{1i}$ are monic irreducible. We have used constructed the field extension $E = F[x]/(q_{11})$ in which $q_{11}$ has a root. To proceed, we need to know that $q_{21}$ is also irreducible over $E$, but we only know that it is irreducible over $K$.

Comment: You probably want a Lemma that says if $f$ is a (non-constant) $K$-polynomial, then there’s a (finite) extension of $K$ generated by all the roots of $f$; in other words, the splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, you can start out with only one polynomial $f:=f_1\cdot f_n$, and look for only the first irreducible factor $q_1$, so $f=q_1^kg$.
Then you obtain $E=K[x]/(q_1)$ and factor $g$ to irreducibles over $E$, but use only the first factor.

And so on..